# IE layout suddenly skewed and has disappearing element

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, browser, layer

I was nearly ready to jump from test mode on a PHP site I am constructing (in other words everything was looking perfect in IE, Firefox and Chrome) when suddenly the wrapper on all pages has skewed downward and the layer that holds the logo is disappearing and reappearing on refresh when using IE (you can see how it should look by browsing both FF and Chrome). I am not aware of changing anything in my CSS so am completely puzzled. If anyone could take a look and guide me toward a fix it would be much appreciated! 
test URL: http://buildarmstrong.com/test/about/index.php
CSS URL: http://buildarmstrong.com/test/CSS/main.css

Comment: Looks fine, even in compatibility mode. The white line above the content isn't aligned with the white line in the background in any browser I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see the difference between the browsers, in fact the only way I could get IE to change the layout at all was by using it's inspector (F12) and changing to quirks mode, however that only aligned the page left - no big deal. Make sure you are using an up-to-date version of IE, I am using IE9 on Win7.